# java gwt compile deploy slow

Tags: java, gwt, deployment, compilation

I have an already existing GWT application which I compile in Eclipse (takes about 80 seconds with 2 Compilation permutations), then I have to build the project with Maven (mvn clean install...) and then I have to deploy everything and restart tomcat. The whole process takes very long, so I was wondering if there may be a faster way to do this? Ain't it possible to make changes in Eclipse which are immediately applied and I just would have to reload the Browser?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up:

- an exploded deployment of your application with your appserver
- use devmode: this uses hot code replacement, so a simple F5 in the browser sees the changes immediately

(the trick behind is behaviour is the codeserver idea: your browser sends back events and stuff to the Java VM of the "development mode application", this is what contains the embedded Jetty server)

This way you can achieve much better turnaround times. Full compile and redeploy is really rarely necessary.

Comment: You don't need to attach a debugger to have hot code replacement: the devmode doesn't run your compiled classes, it compiles them on the fly each time you refresh the page, for clientside code that is.

Comment: how do I explode deployment of the application?

Comment: That depends on your concrete structure. Basically if you can achieve somehow (via Eclipse, your ant script, maven) that the .war you would make finally be unzipped somewhere, then you can get your appserver to use that exploded war as a deployment. Pose a separate concrete question for this. GWT devmode also supports this, even with your fav appserver instead of Jetty.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the [Google Plugin for Eclipse](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/) which allows you (among lots of other things googlish-like) to run your application in *hosted mode* directly from Eclipse.

Cheers,

Comment: I have already installed this plugin but when I run the it I get the following output on the console: [WARN] No startup URLs supplied and no plausible ones found -- use -startupUrl
Reloading web app to reflect changes in PATH/src/main/webapp
[WARN] Server class 'com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JDBCUnloader' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
   [WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:~/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/2.4.0/gwt-dev-2.4.0.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
   Reload completed successfully